# Schwarzian Derivative S(f)=0 then f is a Möbius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove that if the Schwarzian derivative equals 0. Then f must be a Möbius Transformation.

$$
S(f) = \frac{f'''}{f'} - \frac{3}{2}(\frac{f''}{f'})^2 = 0
$$

I know that $S(f)$ can also be represented as

$$
S(f) = (\frac{f''}{f'})'-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{f''}{f'})^2 
$$

Which feels like a more manageable definition. My approach was to set $F:= \frac{f''}{f'} = (ln(f'))'$ and try to manipulate this using the above to find $F$. However, I am stuck on how to manipulate this to my benefit.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/173182

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct solution of the differential equation $S(f)=2u$ for arbitrary analytic $u$ using a classical trick, namely $f=g_1/g_2$ where $g_1,g_2$ are arbitrary (linearly independent to exclude trivialities) solutions of the equation $g''+ug=0$. Assuming that, the OP result follows as $u=0$ implies, $g''=0$, $g_{1,2}$ linear, $f$ Mobius.

The trick goes like this - take $g$ solution for $2f'g'+f''g=0$. This implies (dividing by $f'$ and differentiating) that $2g''+(f''/f')'g+(f''/f')g'=0$ or using $2g'=-(f''/f')'g$ we get $2g''+S(f)g=0$ or $g''+ug=0$.

But now if we take $h(z)=fg(z)$, $h''+uh=f''g+g''f+2f'g'+ufg=f''g+2f'g'=0$ (first equality because $g''+ug=0$, second from the definition of $g$, so $f=h/g$ as required (and the converse is a straight up computation - for us we only need this implication because it shows that $f=h/g, g''=h''=0$)